# Issue in running R script

Tags: r

I am new to R language and I tried some sample programs in R and faced some issues while running the script. The script was running fine in the online compiler (https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler)
and while running in my local machine, the outputs are contradictory. I am running R version 4.0.4 in my local machine.

Code:

```
prod_table <- 
  data.frame(key=c("Printer", "Tablet", "Laptop"),
             price=c(225, 570, 1120))

prod<- sample(prod_table$key, 10, replace=T, prob=c(1, 3, 2))
prod

sales <- prod_table[prod,]$price
sales
```

Output in the online compiler:

`[1]  225 1120 1120 1120 1120  225  225  225  225 1120`

Output in my local machine:

`[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Is there any error in my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an error in your code. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The online compiler is running R 3.4.4 where `data.frame` call had by default `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. This has changed since R 4.0.0 so the short answer is if you add `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in your code it will work.

```
prod_table <- data.frame(key=c("Printer", "Tablet", "Laptop"),
                         price=c(225, 570, 1120), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

---

However, the reason why it works is because you are sampling on `prod_table$key` which is a factor and factors are stored as integers internally and these integers work as row index to subset in line `prod_table[prod,]$price`. A safer option is to sample row index directly.

```
prod_table <- data.frame(key=c("Printer", "Tablet", "Laptop"),
             price=c(225, 570, 1120))

prod<- sample(seq(nrow(prod_table)), 10, replace=T, prob=c(1, 3, 2))
prod

sales <- prod_table$price[prod]
sales
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now the code is working after setting stringsAsFactors = TRUE. Thanks a lot!